# Как реализовать задержку рисования точек canvas

Tags: java, android, kotlin

ниже приведен код, который позволяет что-нибудь нарисовать на экране, и через несколько секунд как пользователь отпустил палец, перерисовывается заново автоматически.

Нужно чтобы при перересовке точки рисовались с определенным интервалом(задержкой) относительно друг друга. Как это реализовать?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
internal lateinit var dv: DrawingView
var points: ArrayList<IntermediatePoint>? = null
private var mPaint: Paint? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    dv = DrawingView(this)
    setContentView(dv)
    mPaint = Paint()
    mPaint!!.isAntiAlias = true
    mPaint!!.isDither = true
    mPaint!!.color = Color.GREEN
    mPaint!!.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    mPaint!!.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
    mPaint!!.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
    mPaint!!.strokeWidth = 12f
    points = ArrayList();


}

inner class DrawingView(internal var context: Context) : View(context) {

    var width: Int? = 0
    var height: Int? = 0
    private var mBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    private var mCanvas: Canvas? = null
    private val mPath: Path
    private val mBitmapPaint: Paint
    private val circlePaint: Paint
    private val circlePath: Path

    private var mX: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var mY: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private val TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4f


    init {
        mPath = Path()
        mBitmapPaint = Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
        circlePaint = Paint()
        circlePath = Path()
        circlePaint.isAntiAlias = true
        circlePaint.color = Color.BLUE
        circlePaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        circlePaint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.MITER
        circlePaint.strokeWidth = 4f
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        mCanvas = Canvas(mBitmap!!)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)



        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap!!, 0f, 0f, mBitmapPaint)

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint!!)
        canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint)

    }

    private fun touch_start(x: Float, y: Float) {

        mPath.reset()
        mPath.moveTo(x, y)
        mX = x
        mY = y

    }

    private fun touch_move(x: Float, y: Float) {
        val dx = Math.abs(x - mX)
        val dy = Math.abs(y - mY)
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2)
            mX = x
            mY = y

            circlePath.reset()
            Log.d("KAK","TAK");

            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30f, Path.Direction.CW)

        }
    }

    private fun touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY)
        circlePath.reset()
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas!!.drawPath(mPath, mPaint!!)
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset()
        mCanvas?.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)

        //    for (item in points!!){
        //      Log.d("TEST X: ", item.x.toString())
        //     Log.d("TEST Y: ", item.y.toString())
        //     Log.d("TEST TIME: ", item.time.toString())
        //  }


    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {


        val x = event.x
        val y = event.y
        val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
        Log.d("WTF", time.toString())
        Log.d("KEK ", "xMain: = )$x            yMain: = $y")

        // var point:IntermediatePoint = IntermediatePoint(time,x,y);
        // points?.add(point)


        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                Log.d("KEK ", "xStart: = )$x            yStart: = $y")
                var point: IntermediatePoint = IntermediatePoint(time, x, y);
                points?.add(point)
                touch_start(x, y)
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {

                Log.d("KEK ", "xMove: = )$x            yMove: = $y")
                var point: IntermediatePoint = IntermediatePoint(time, x, y);
                points?.add(point)
                touch_move(x, y)
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                Log.d("KEK ", "xUp: = )$x            yUp: = $y")

                var point: IntermediatePoint = IntermediatePoint(time, x, y);
                points?.add(point)
                touch_up()
                invalidate()

                Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {

                    for (i in points!!.indices) {

                        Log.d("KEK ", "xStartPost: = )${points!![i].x}            yStartPost: = ${points!![i].y}")
                        if (i == 0) {
                            touch_start(points!![0].x, points!![0].y)
                            invalidate();
                        } else if (i == points!!.size - 1) {
                            touch_move(points!![i].x, points!![i].y)
                            invalidate();
                        } else {
                            touch_move(points!![i].x, points!![i].y)
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    }

                    points?.clear()

                }, 5000)


            }
        }


        return true
    }





}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1. Пока длится анимация (состояние изменяется), нужно знать, сколько времени прошло. Для этого нужно завести поле, в которое в начале анимации будет записано uptimeMillis.
2. В onDraw нужно рисовать точки, исходя из текущего состояния, которое вычисляется из разности текущего uptimeMillis и сохранённого.
3. Пока анимация не закончена, из onDraw нужно вызывать invalidate. Тогда эта вью будет рисоваться и в следующем кадре.

В целом — как-то так.

P. S. Нуллабилити сделано не для того чтобы делать всё нуллабельным и расставлять восклицательные знаки. Смешение венгерской нотации с нормальным кодом выглядит страшно.